# Add serialized object to current user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have a view that accepts serialized Album object and assign the owner to current user

```
class AlbumListViewer(APIView):    
    def post(self, request, format = None):
        request.data['user_id'] = request.user.id
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The error I get is

> null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

My Serializer looks like  this

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('id','album_name', 'date_created','user')
```

And finally my Model looks like this

```
class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

I have tried assigning a User ID in the JSON data but it is not being recognized by the serializer, anyway to assign this serialized object and give it a owner before saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have some problems in your AlbumListViewer. Do not try to add to the validatated_data anything. Instead pass on partial=True to the serializer, and after validation, use the save() method to save the missing values.

```
class AlbumListViewer(APIView):   
    def post(self, request, format = None):
        serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            serializer.save(user=user)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```